# Pause form submissions while upgrading plugins

Tags: plugins, forms, updates

Is there a way to pause form submissions during the plugin/WordPress core upgrade process. The problem I am trying to solve is that when upgrading a live site at some point the default WP 'Briefly unavailable for scheduled maintenance' message appears.

In most cases this is fine, the user can simply reload their page. But a site I am working on has some complex (and long) multi-page forms. It is entirely possible that a user could be on one of these forms when the upgrade button is hit. They could then in theory press submit at the very time the database is unavailable - meaning their data is lost.

Is there anything that I could do about this? I am currently using one particular plugin to manage forms, but in theory this is a problem that could exist for any plugin, or indeed any form submission code you'd care to create.

Thoughts and theories welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to check if wordpress is actively running the core upgrade process. First, you could check the `WP_INSTALLING` constant, or use the [wp_installing()](https://gist.github.com/ohmanger/2b72f072038d5df7c215) function.

Wordpress will also utilize a `.maintenance` or `maintenance.php` file if you'd like to present any custom messages to users while the upgrade process is happening. Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/ohmanger/2b72f072038d5df7c215) that goes beyond Wordpress's [sparse documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_maintenance) on the topic.